# What is the proper syntax for concatenating text and variables in SpreadsheetApp functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

```
    function namedRanges() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      for(var i=3; i<504; i++) {
        var r = ss.getRange('A3:Q3'+i);
        ss.setNamedRange('Song'+i, r);
      }
    }
```

The above formula, is not stepping thru the 500 song rows in my spreadsheet and naming each row, "Song 3" for row A3-Q3, etc. (starting at row 3 as I have headers in rows 1 and 2) as I expected.

So what I am trying to do is create named ranges for all 500 songs in the sheet.

What I am expecting:

- Name  - Range
- Song3 - Songs!A3:Q3
- Song4 - Songs!A4:Q4
- Song5 - Songs!A5:Q5
- etc.

What I am getting:

- Song3 - Songs!A3:Q33
- Song4 - Songs!A3:Q34
- Song5 - Songs!A3:Q35
- etc.

I have spent two days trying to track this down by searching (in vain). I'm sure it's easy. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Go through your loop piece-by-piece, and explain in detail what each is doing. Say it out loud. You should find the error pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
function namedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i=100; i<601; i++) {
    var r = ss.getRange(('A'+i+':Q'+i));
    ss.setNamedRange('Song'+i, r);
  }
}
```